# Securing other url's in Magento

Tags: wordpress, security, magento, ssl, https

So, I've got a Magento installation with Wordpress integration. I've got an install where I need to have SSL to cover payments, and unfortunately the Wordpress folder isn't secure and serving images through http. In order to get the green lock, I need to secure the entire wordpress folder.

I know in the backend of Magento, you can specify which folders belong to skin, media and js to secure, but how (if it is in the same parent directory) would I secure the wordpress folder?

Answer (score 0):

yes you can secure your wordpress setup with extra wordpress plugin

use [this link](http://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-https/) this is very good plugin to use with wordpress to get SSL certficate to all pages as well as in admin area.

Also there is one another alternative solution to make some change in code to use this useful link

http://yoast.com/wordpress-ssl-setup/

*Pls not that i am not associate with any of the above link.A purpose to share this link to solve your problem.*

hope this will sure help you.

Comment: this isn't in relation to wordpress integration WITHIN magento, though.

Comment: yes i know but wordpress is totla different in your host to manage your blog. you can add SSL to your all wordpress pages

Answer (score 0):

Try to add that in your httpd-ssl.conf (one of your Apache config files)